# MySql/mariadb - SELECT 0 = 'N;' returns true

Tags: php, mariadb

I was going through some MySql (mariadb) report looking for why I was getting too many rows in a report and found that the column being queried which stores serialized php and matches another column value is falsely matching.

`where m.section = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.other,CHAR(59),2),CHAR(58),-1)`

This is fine. `m.section` contains a number. `s.other` might have a value `a:1:{s:3:"foo";i:4;}`, so it is matching the `4` in that data.

Then I found that some `n.other` records are storing null. Php's serialize outputs a capital N followed by a semicolon to represent a null.

```php
echo serialize(null); // outputs N;

echo is_null(unserialize('N;')); // outputs 1
```

So php thinks `N;` is null.

In my query, when `m.section` equals zero, it is matching the record. Zero equals php null? Lets test that.

```sql
SELECT 0 = 'N;'
```

outputs
`1` !

What else equals null that shouldn't?

```
select 1 = 'N;' --> 0
select 0 = null --> null
select 0 is null --> 0
select 'N;' is null --> 0
```

Am I going mad? How come zero equals php's serial null?

Comment: nulls are are treated as non-values in SQL so [relations between them are always false](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/null-values/).

Comment: Hmm. Hmmmmmmm. So null-placeholder-value `N;` is false becasue its a non-value. And I'm comparing zero which is falsy to false, and therefore that is equal to `1`. When what I really want is to compare the integer zero to null to get false and compare zero to zero to get true. I think I need a case statement. Ok cheers @danblack!

Comment: Storing serialized data in database is a horrible practice. Using this data in the queries is despicable.

Comment: MariaDB doesn't unserialize php data. If you want NULL in the SQL column that can be done directly to conform with the usual SQL rules associated with NULL.

Comment: PHP **DOESN'T** think that "N; is null." PHP thinks that **when serialized**, null is represented as N. N is not a PHP null. It's a serialized null. And ; is not a part of value but a delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not PHP, its MariaDB.

Through the [type conversion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/type-conversion/) rules, 'N;' is converted (badly) to `DECIMAL`.

During the conversion it gets a 0 value. And with the equality test to 0 becomes true.

Looking at the warnings of the `select 0 = 'N;'` will result in:

```
Warning     1292    Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: 'N;'
```

ref: https://dbfiddle.uk/4rZ0N8CF